# why there special state this IP block `NON-RIPE-NCC-MANAGED-ADDRESS-BLOCK`?

Tags: ip

When I query IP's whois information:

```
inetnum:        47.0.0.0 - 49.11.255.255
netname:        NON-RIPE-NCC-MANAGED-ADDRESS-BLOCK
descr:          IPv4 address block not managed by the RIPE NCC
```

What's the `RIPE NCC`'s function? why there special state this IP block `47.0.0.0 - 49.11.255.255` is `NON-RIPE-NCC-MANAGED-ADDRESS-BLOCK`, what's the significance of this?

---

**EDIT**

I know under IANA there are four Regional Internet Registries:
`RIPE NCC`, `APNIC`, `ARIN` and `LACNIC`.

but why there it only special `NON-RIPE-NCC-MANAGED-ADDRESS-BLOCK`? 
I use other whois tool query it shows `49.11.255.255` is under `APNIC`.

why it not special `NON-ARIN-MANAGED-ADDRESS-BLOCK` or `NON-LACNIC-MANAGED-ADDRESS-BLOCK`?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

IP address assignment to organizations is distributed across several [Regional Internet Registries](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Regional_Internet_registry) (RIRs) which oversee their own regions, such as RIPE (Europe) or ARIN (North America). They don't assign addresses out of a single shared pool – instead each RIR gets its own allocation from IANA and only assigns addresses out of that pool.

Each RIR has its own WHOIS server, and your client needs to somehow know *which* WHOIS server it's supposed to ask for whatever IP address. That is, you cannot always query `whois.ripe.net` and expect it to work every time. Some clients have the top-level RIR assignments and corresponding WHOIS servers hardcoded in the source code – and that list, of course, can get out-of-date.

However, often the WHOIS databases have 'stub' entries for foreign addresses, so instead of simply returning "No results" the server actually returns an entry that says "It's not my responsibility to know about it". Sometimes this is because the database schema requires all addresses to have a 'parent', e.g. if your address was obtained from ARIN but you want to announce it in RIPE's region and have to enter it into RIPE's database somehow.

So there's nothing special about this block, other than your WHOIS client is asking the wrong server about it (possibly because the client is more than a few years old).

Comment: Thanks for this insight! It helped me today!

Answer (score 1):

It means the address block isn't managed by Réseaux IP Européens Network Coordination Centre. They oversee the allocation and registration of Internet number resources in their region.

https://www.ripe.net/about-us/what-we-do